# Как сделать автозапуск приложения вместе с включением компьютера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, ос, командная-строка

Есть код приложения и я хочу чтобы он запускался при включении компьютера. 
Однако не знаю как это правильно сделать, все мои попытки оканчивались тем, что приложение **`запускалось с отсутствием картинок`**, которые я использую в этом коде, помогите пожалуйста.

Вот часть кода отвечающая за автозапуск (я не особо понимаю как именно он работает, я просто нашел код в интернете)

```
def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
            if file_path == "":
                file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
            with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
                bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```

Вот как выглядит приложение при автозапуске:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вот как оно выглядит, когда я запускаю его сам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам код:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
import os
import random

import requests
import json
import datetime
import winreg

from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import QTranslator, QLocale, QLibraryInfo
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from ext import *








class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окна
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setWindowTitle('Unapp')
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(845,535))
        #Вызываем класс с заставкой
        

        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)


        
        #Кнопка с домиком(главной страницей)                                 
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Кнопка с заметками
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('калькулятор.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #кнопка с калькулятором
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        #Кнопка с текстовым редактором
        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))


        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

               
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))


        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
#1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        fontleo = QFont('Century Gothic', 25, QFont.Bold)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
#Ленин виджет с пожеланиями
        #self.leo = Example()
        
        
        #self.leo.setParent(self.page_1)






#календарь
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 380))
        self.calendarWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(Calendar_StyleSheet)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)


        #self.main = App()

        #self.main.w_root.setParent(self.page_1)
        #self.main.w_root.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430,0,345,153))
        

        #self.main.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(345, 165))
        #self.main.move(455,0)
        

        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setKerning(True)

        #self.CAL = Calculator(
            #title='Calculator App : Made by Rahul',
            #parent=None,
            #uiFile='form/ui_calculator.ui')
        #self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.CAL.window)  


        

        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #336699;')
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        #Заметки
        #self.view = AppView()

        
        # instance of the controller
        #self.ctrl = AppController(view=self.view)


        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)

        #self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.view)

        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        
        
        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        #Текстовый редактор
        font2 = QtGui.QFont()
        font2.setPointSize(12)
        font2.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        #self.gg = Main()
        #self.gg.setFont(font2)


        
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               


        #self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.gg)




        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')


       


        
        
       
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
# verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
# verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
    #Функция для добавления приложения в автозапуск Windows
        key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, "Date Time", 0, winreg.REG_SZ,"D:\\Project\\TRY3.py")
        key.Close()
    #Функция для показа текущего времени
    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

Calendar_StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: #6d86a4;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6d86a4;
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;  
    image: none;              
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: #6d86a4; 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Иконка_Горы.png'))
    app1 = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    PATH_LANGUAGE = r'C:/python2/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/translations/qtbase_ru.qm'
    translator = QTranslator(app1)
    translator.load(PATH_LANGUAGE, "ru_RU")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Пропишите абсолютные пути к файлам. Или пути относительно файла скрипта (а не места запуска).  В остальном  думаю суть проблемы полностью описана в ответе @S. Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы запускаете как-то так:

**`python D:\_Qt\main.py`**

где  `<D:\_Qt\>` - какой-то каталог где лежит ваш **main.py**

---

А надо так:

1. перейдите командой ОС в каталог где лежит ваш **main.py**
2. и запустите так: **`python main.py`**

---

---

**Update**

Попробуйте распечатать то что вы туда пишите:

```
def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "r") as bat_file:
        _file = bat_file.read()    
    print(_file)    # что в нем интересного вы увидели ?
```

Comment: Запустил так как вы указали, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Так проблема в том, что при обычном запуске приложения все работает исправно, а вот при автозапуске, после включения компьютера, пропадают иконки и картинки, которые я использую в этом коде

Comment: @ivapop добавьте в вопрос и покажите строки из АВТОЗАПУСКА как вы это делаете.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @ivapop уже лучше. Покажите строки из `open.bat`, которые запускают ваше приложение. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: Тут есть проблема, вот строчки кода для автозапуска должны создавать .bat файл по пути **C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup**, однако у меня никакой файл там не появляется, но .py файл появляется в диспетчере задач, в списке приложений для автозапуска, появляется.

Comment: @ivapop я добавил в свой ответ некоторые рекомендации - проверьте.

Comment: Файл не появился и не открылся.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет Виндоувс не знаю. Но код думаю следует подправить.

```py
def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
            if file_path == "":
                file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
            bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % (USER_NAME)
            with open(bat_path + '\\open.bat', 'w') as bat_file:
                bat_file.write(r'start %s' % (file_path))
```